# Is "be" really required after "may" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> Age maybe has slowed down MT Vasudevan Nair but his creativity remains undiminished.

I think it is an egregious error to use may be this style. Shouldn't there be just "may" before "slowed down"?

Comment: Age is uncountable: "Age maybe has slowed down ..." is still awkward, and would normally be "Maybe age has slowed down ..." (or "Perhaps age ...") but they might have been intending "Age may have slowed down ..."

Comment: Neither the word *may* nor the word *be* appear in your quoted sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You use "be" and "may" in the title, but  the example uses "maybe".

You have to be careful that "may be" and "maybe" are different things, not different spellings of the same thing.

In the example, "maybe" is correct (even if the word order can be improved). Since "maybe" is a simple word, one should not remove pars of it randomly.

---

Consider the following:

> I saw a woman.

Is it OK to remove "man"? Is it OK to remove "wo"? Of course not.

> - **I saw a wo**<strike>man</strike>.
> - **I saw a** <strike>wo</strike>**man**.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is not the case that "may + be = maybe" even if that is the etymology.  Rather, "may" and "be" are verbs, with "may" generally an auxiliary, while "maybe" is an adverb.

In the sentence you provide, try replacing "maybe" with "perhaps" or "possibly" and read it again.  This is the sense I think the original author intended.  As noted in a comment, this is a little awkward to my ear and I would prefer the "has" to go before the "maybe" or one the synonyms, but it still works as-is.